# `conj` and `disj` for lists in clojure? Possible other data structures to use for this? Contains SCCEE

Tags: data-structures, clojure

For a class project I am implementing the [Bron-Kerbosch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm) for finding maximal cliques in a graph. With help from others on SO I have gotten down to the final few issues.

This link (http://pastebin.com/2GUPZFnR) contains a SSCCE of my current implementation that outlines the issue. The issue I think lies with my use of `disj` to find the intersection of two lists. I think this based on the error given when I call `BK-Call` with the "sanity" input.

```
fptests.core> (BK-Call (sanity1))
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IPersistentSet  clojure.core/disj (core.clj:1449)
```

This error tracks down to a few lines in my Bron-Kerbosch function itself

```
(defn Bron-Kerbosch [r p x graph cliques]
  (cond (and (empty? p) (empty? x)) (conj cliques r)
        :else
        (let [neigh (neighV graph (dec (count p)))]
          (loop [loop-clq '(cliques)
                 loop-cnt '(dec (count p))
                 loop-p '(p)
                 loop-x '(x)]
            (cond (= -1 loop-cnt) loop-clq
                  :else
                  (recur (conj loop-clq (Bron-Kerbosch (conj r loop-cnt) (conj p neigh) (disj x neigh)))
                         (dec loop-cnt)
                         (disj p loop-cnt)
                         (conj x loop-cnt)))))))
```

Specifically in the recursive call to the function in the `recur` form. Though this issue I think applies to all uses of `conj` and `disj`. It seems that `conj` "works" but not in the manner I assumed.

```
fptests.core> (disj '(1) '(1 2 3))
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IPersistentSet  clojure.core/disj (core.clj:1449)
fptests.core> (conj '(1) '(2 3))
((2 3) 1)
```

I assumed that `(conj '(1) '(2 3))` would return `(1 2 3)` and not `(1 (2 3))`. So it seems my use of lists in the function overall is the issue. Is there a way that I could overcome this issue?

I would have to imagine there are functions like `conj` and `disj` that work with lists. I guess my other option if this is not true is to use some other data structure in the algorithm. What would be appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `cons`, `rest` and `concat`.

```
user=> (cons 1 '(2 3))
(1 2 3)
user=> (cons '(1) '(2 3))
((1) 2 3)
user=> (cons 1 ())
(1)
user=> (rest '(1 2 3))
(2 3)
user=> (concat '(1) '(2 3))
(1 2 3)
```

Comment: I suppose then I would have to write a small helper function to find the intersection of two lists; instead of `disj`?

Comment: The other issue I see is `(cons '(1) '(2 3))` evaluating to `((1) 2 3)` and not `(1 2 3)`, Is there a way to have the later happen?

Comment: Does `remove` works fine for your issue? `(def x 'b)` then `(remove #{x} '(a b c))` returns `(a c)`,
`(remove (set '(b d)) '(a b c b d))` returns `(a c)`. And use `concat` for `(concat '(1) '(2 3))` returns `(1 2 3)`.

Comment: Ooops, looked that over too quickly. // Remove in itself does not work, I need to find the intersection of the values in the lists. I think a small helper function will do the trick. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `(filter (set l1) l2)` will return the intersection of l1 and l2

Answer (score 2):

I would indeed suggest using a data structure more suited to the problem at hand, namely a set.

You're already using Clojure hash sets in your graph representation (`(repeat n #{})` in `empty-graph`); the `r`, `p` and `x` parameters of the Bron-Kerbosch step function are all conceptually sets, so it makes sense to represent them as Clojure sets as well.

With that choice of representation, things will become simpler for you – set intersection can be computed using `clojure.set/intersection`, `disj` works for removing individual keys etc.

---

On a separate note, it would be more natural to use `if` rather than `cond` in `Bron-Kerbosch` (both `cond`s in that function actually only have two branches). More importantly, you'll want to remove the quotes from the init expressions in your `loop` – `'(dec (count p))` (notice the `'`), to take one example, is a two-element list, not a number. (It's also somewhat unusual in Clojure for function names to include capital letters, but of course this is purely a matter of style.)

Comment: Great advice. I think all of those inits are meant to be lists though, so `'(...)` should be replaced by `(list ...)` in each case, except the `dec` of course.